# JavaFX 3D Graphics: Mouse click position on 3D object

Tags: 3d, javafx, javafx-2

I just played around with the [Oracle JavaFX Sample 3D Graphics app](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/sampleapp3d.htm#CJAHFAF)
I am wondering if it is possible to **calculate the current mouse position relative
to the 3d platform**. I would like some info e.g. if the mouse hovers a 3d object.
Is that possible in any way (Maybe with the given camera translations etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the PickResult class from any MouseEvent,
this is just the basic usage ..

```
...{
    shape3D.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
        PickResult pr = e.getPickResult();
        System.out.println(pr.getIntersectedPoint());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I whish swing had this, too :D

Comment: But pls change the method name. It must be `setOnMouseEntered`

Comment: You're right... I just typed it out.. but at least you got the picture ... ;)
It's also good to check for if(intersectedNode != null) as it can some times.. The listener is also best on the Scene rather than node, but for Illustration purposes I used node..

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaboration. I am just starting with JavaFX and this vas really helpful :)